# Is a werewolf a "homlupo" or a "luphomo"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

During the day, a werewolf has a human form, so it is logical to call him a *luphomo*. During some nights, a werewolf has a wolf form, so it is logical to call him a *homlupo*. Are both forms used? Is one used for both cases? Is it correct to call a werewolf *homlupo* during the day?

Comment: If you wanted to translate the English word morpheme-for-morpheme, it would be _virlupo_!

Answer (score 8):

When they are in wolf form, they are a *homlupo*, and when they are in human form, they are a *luphomo*. To insist on one form over the other could be seen as a kind of diurnal chauvinism—which body shape is the more authentic?

If you are talking to a *lupulo* on the phone, and you are not sure of their current shape, you can avoid giving offence by using the word *likantropo*, or the more inclusive *formŝanĝisto* and *metamorfozulo*.

(Note that Zamenhof chose to use *lupfantomo* in one of the *Fabeloj*. This is still, more or less, the official word. However, is it possible that he was referring to the *ghost* of a werewolf, and omitted the *-hom-* to avoid pedanticism? Who can say?)

Comment: No one of the many people that I have heard using one of these words makes the distinction in meaning that you propose. People in general just use one of the two, depending on whether they have played the card game "The Werewolves of Millers Hollow" at a youth Esperanto event or at a family Esperanto event (see my answer).

Comment: Perhaps my position is uncommon, but it is (or was) comparable to the position taken by the respected author of PMEG. Consequently, I feel the two downvotes I have received, including one just now, to be deeply unfair.

Answer (score 7):

Both of these words are used quite a lot, because the card game [*The Werewolves of Millers Hollow*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Werewolves_of_Millers_Hollow) is quite popular at Esperanto events (at least in Europe). The word *homlupo* is used at youth Esperanto events, while *luphomo* is used at family Esperanto events. They have precisely the same meaning.

It is hard to say which one of them should be preferred. The only form listed in [PIV](http://vortaro.net) is *lupfantomo*, which I have never heard being used in practice, and which has been criticized for being very misleading, as werewolves are not ghosts. I have heard the argument that *homlupo* is to be prefered, because according to the legend the real nature of the being is its wolf nature. This is the reason why I personally prefer *homlupo*, though given that I regularly attend family Esperanto events and no longer youth Esperanto events, I now use *luphomo* more often, just to ensure that I am more readily understood by those used to this word.

Comment: [La Lupfantomo](http://bertilow.com/literaturo/lupfantomo.html).